# vuejs best way to pass reactive data

Tags: authentication, vue.js, reactive

Using vue.js. I have an authentication file(auth.js) where the user info is stored when a authentication state change is detected. Other parts of the website need to be changed when the user info changes.
How do I do this?
I can import auth.js, but then those other parts only user the original state.

Answer (score 1):

If your components rely on global state, then you should extract that state out into a store, which you can do using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/). Here's a basic example that changes the navigation bar when a `loggedIn` flag is set to true:

```
// Define our vuex store with a loggedIn state property
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setLoggedIn(state, value) {
      state.loggedIn = value
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('navbar', {
  template: `
   <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-if="loggedIn"><a href="#" @click="logOut">Logout</a></li>
      <li v-else>Login</li>
    </ul>
   </div>`,
  computed: {
    loggedIn() {
      return store.state.loggedIn // return loggedIn from vuex
    }
  },
  methods:{
    logOut(){
      store.commit('setLoggedIn', false); // mutate loggedIn state in vuex
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed:{
    loggedIn(){
      return store.state.loggedIn // return loggedIn from vuex
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logIn() {
      store.commit('setLoggedIn', true) // mutate loggedIn state in vuex
    }
  }
})
```

Remember, this simply a flag to set the log in status to update the view, you should do additional checks server side before allowing your user to access sensitive information.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69boyqbg/